# Select class of a span with same two elements with css

Tags: css, duplicates

i have this little problem, i have `<span class="a a">some text</span>.`

i would like to apply css like this:

```
      .a.a{
           color: red;
         }
```

but it does not work, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question gives virtually no information and your example CSS rule is totally meaningless.

Comment: i have update my question sorry

Comment: Because `#8984` is not a valid color code. A hexadecimal color code can either be 6 or 3 characters. For example `#898` or `#8984AA`

Comment: `class="a a"` is exactly equivalent to `class="a"`. You can't duplicate them and expect something different to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the class twice in the markup doesn't make any difference than specifying it just once.

> However, from what I have observed, creating a rule with same selector twice, emphasizes it more, (observed in Firefox).

So, with the following rules,

```
.someclass.someclass
{ 
    color: blue;
}

.someclass
{ 
    color: red;
}
```

The one with `color: blue;` takes precedence.

Comment: That is due to [specificity scores](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Comment: @Phylogenesis I did not know that, thank you for the link.